# Share code between a class and a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, activator

I am developing a class that creates an instance of a class (using `Activator.CreateInstance`) that is specified to the class (either as a type parameter or as a parameter to the constructor), so it is rather pointless to create an instance of the class when the class creates an instance anyway, so therefor passing in the type using generics makes sense. E.g.

```
var foo = new Foo<Bar>();
```

However, this makes the class impossible to be used at run-time tho, since the type parameter is declared at compile-time.

To use this at run-time the constructor would need to take the parameter as an argument. E.g.

```
var foo = new Foo(new Bar());
```

The rest of code in the classes are the same though, so if this were to be two different classes, then there would be a lot of duplicate code.

## Questions:

- How do I share code and avoid duplicating code?
- Can (and should) this be two constructors of the same class?
- Am I taking the wrong approach? Maybe `new Foo(typeof(Bar))` ?

Comment: Please explain what is the purpose behind this.. Currently it is unclear/too broad.. I assume for "sharing code" - composition/inheritance.  Two constructors - yes, possible. `typeof(Bar)` - this is something else - depends what you want ot do

Comment: I am curious what your implementation looks like. From the question this sounds more like a candidate for inheritance than generic. Or if `Foo` is dependent on `Bar` then the common properties/methods could of one could invoke the other and avoid the duplication.

Comment: *I am developing a class that creates an instance of a class that is specified to the class (either as a type parameter or as a parameter to the constructor), so it is rather pointless to create an instance of the class when the class creates an instance anyway, so therefor passing in the type using generics makes sense.* ... huh?

Comment: This is unanswerable without a minimal code sample that shows *why* Foo has a type parameter, and *what* it is doing with an instance of Bar, and why, if Foo and Bar share code, you didn't use inheritance to share it.

Comment: @AntP Maybe he wants new `Foo(type)`? Or `new Foo(classFactory)`. Or just a little help resolving ambiguous antecedents.

Comment: What methods from Bar are you intending to use in Foo?

Comment: @GiladGreen, then how do I make a class with two constructors? One normal constructor, and one generic constructor?

Comment: @Fred - you can't. A generic class is a different class than a non-generic. Have two classes where the generic one inherits from the non-generic (or the other way - depending on case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have now figured this out!

I make two separate classes; one normal and one generic. The generic one inherits from the normal one and has a generic constructor that calls the constructor from the base class.

The normal class needs constructor that accept `Type` as its argument (this constructor does not have to be `public`, it can be `protected`). This constructor is called from the generic class.

```
    public class Foo
    {
        private readonly object _bar;

        public Foo(Bar bar) : this(bar.GetType())
        {
        }

        protected Foo(Type bar)
        {
            _bar = Activator.CreateInstance(bar);
        }

        public void Write()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_bar);
        }
    }

    public class Foo<T> : Foo
    {
        public Foo() : base(typeof(T))
        {
        }
    }
```

Now I can instantiate my class using either the normal class or the generic class.

```
    var foo1 = new Foo(new Bar());
    foo1.Write();

    var foo2 = new Foo<Bar>();
    foo2.Write();
```

Comment: Why is the constructor Foo(Bar bar) creating a new instance? You can simply _bar = bar.

Comment: @R.Rusev, because it is what this particular class is designed to do. However, I edited the post to rewrite it so that only one constructor performs that task, and now it calls the other constructor to avoid duplicating code.

Comment: So the purpose of the class ( Foo ) is to always create new instance of the specified class ( Bar ), even when it is done by giving an existing instance of that class ( Bar ) to the constructor of class ( Foo )?

Comment: @R.Rusev, yes. The reason for this is because it should be able to create new instances at run-time. It gets a `string` then find an instance of that class in a dictionary then feeds that to `Foo` which creates a new instance of the class of that instance since it knows its type.

Comment: Why not stick to just new Foo<Bar>(); in this case? Otherwise it look like bad design to me. Just a suggestion, you know your case best. :)

Answer (score 0):

I attempted your problem with a custom constructor. It did not work. This is because C# treats Foo`<Bar`> and Foo`<Int`> As completely other types. So a constructor that receives the type does not work.

The next solution was the Introduction of a Generic static class to help with this:

```
[TestClass]
public class FooBarTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFooBar()
    {
        var foo = new Foo<Bar>();
        var foo2 = Foo.CreateFoo(new Bar());
        Assert.AreEqual(foo.GetType(), foo2.GetType());
    }
}


public class Foo<T> 
{
    public Foo()
    {

    }

    public Foo(T obj)
    {

    }
}

public static class Foo
{
    public static Foo<TType> CreateFoo<TType>(TType obj)
    {
        return new Foo<TType>(obj);
    }
}

public class Bar
{

}
```

This will mean that the Static class Foo (No generics) will create the object for you. Unit test included to check the effect!